# Issue with scaling items that are too large in order to fit into WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a canvas that I am populating with code behind (C#), what I am drawing is a dynamic mockup of a building based on parameters so I need it to scale to fit the canvas area 100% EVEN when it exceeds the canvas width and height. The only solutions I have been able to find take the canvas elements and stretch them to fit, I need to shrink them to fit.

This is the closest I have come:

```
<Grid>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" Background="Transparent" Margin="0"  Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="600" >

            <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"  />
            </Canvas.LayoutTransform>

        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

But this doesn't scale perfectly, however it's the closest I've come. What is the best solution for this?

EDIT: Code Behind:

```
var areaRectangle = new Rectangle();
areaRectangle.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
areaRectangle.StrokeThickness = 3;

var areaTextblock = new TextBlock();
areaTextblock.Text = child.Name;
areaTextblock.Margin = new Thickness(48, 6, 0, 0);

areaRectangle.Width = (childData.Length.GetValueOrDefault() - 6);
areaRectangle.Height = (childData.Width.GetValueOrDefault() - 6);

Canvas.SetLeft(areaRectangle, areaLeft + 3);
Canvas.SetTop(areaRectangle, 3);
Canvas.SetLeft(areaTextblock, areaLeft + 3);
Canvas.SetTop(areaTextblock, 3);

Canvas.Children.Add(areaRectangle);
Canvas.Children.Add(areaTextblock);
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use a Canvas instead of a Grid?  A Grid can automatically expand itself to contain the child elements (and then the surrounding ViewBox could shrink the whole package to fit the window).  If you really need to use a Canvas then you may need to change its Width and Height in code-behind in order to fit the contents.

Comment: @RogerN I come from Web Dev, and when we draw (shy of SVG) we just use a canvas, I don't know it made sense at the time

Comment: What is the drawing/mockup? Is it an image or something else? Can you post the code behind?

Comment: @CJK added the gist of how elements are being added

Comment: Couldn't you set the height and width properties of the rectangle in your code behind?

Comment: @CJK I could, but I would have to scale them all to a ratio based on the size of the canvas, which granted is a static width and height, but I was hoping for a xaml solution